# "MySQL Error Code 1114: The table is full" keeps showing up

Tags: mysql

I'm running  MySQL 8.0.23 on Windows server 2019.
Two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblp` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datum` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_dat` (`datum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

and

```
    CREATE TABLE `tblpdet` (
        `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
        `katbr` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `redid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`redid`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_katbr` (`katbr`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tblpdet_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tblp` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Now, if I execute:

```
select katbr, min(date(datum)) 
from tblp p 
join tblpdet d on p.id = d.id
group by katbr;
```

I get error

> Error Code: 1114. The table 'd:\tmp#sql1e5c_18_1eb' is full

If I execute:

```
select katbr, min(redid)
from tblpdet 
group by katbr;
```

then it works fine.

Result should return some 120.000 rows.

Here are global settings relevant to this issue:

```
> innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=51539607552
```

Table tblp has some 5.800.000 rows, and tblpdet has some 43.000.000 rows.
Data folder of MySQL is on SSD (mirrored) drive with 800GB of free space.
Total RAM is 128GB;
Machine has 2 processors with total of 20 cores, running only MySQL (at the moment).

Everything I read is ending up with 'not enough disk space', or wrong configuration of innodg_data_file_path. Anybody help?

Comment: Is there enough space on your d: drive ? Do you have some limites set in the innodb_data_file_path or tmp_table_size setting in your my.cnf configuration file ?

Comment: There's 800GB of free space on d:, tmp_file_size=7516192768. What do you mean by "limits on innodb_data_file_path"? As I mentioned, innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend

Answer (score 2):

First post so be kind.

I have a similar issue (Error Code: 1114. The table '/tmp/#sql2cc_b_3e' is full) with selecting and joining large datasets with sort and group by.  The issue is present in 8.0.24 but not 8.0.22 or prior.

I tested this by exporting the database out of 8.0.24 where I received the error and importing into 8.0.20 where the same query runs successfully.  I then updated without changing any other settings to 8.0.24 and the same query fails.  I have also done a fresh install of 8.0.24 and also receive the error there.